# Is there a way drop records from Smartsheets using SQL server in a CData Smartsheet Task?

Tags: sql-server, smartsheet-api, ssis-2019

I'm trying to drop records from a Smartsheet using a SQL statement in a CData Smartsheet Task but am getting the following error:

> [SmartsheetExecutorTask] Error: An error occurred while preparing SQL statement. Error: Malformed SQL Statement: Unexpected token encountered

The code works if I remove the Inner Join but the SQL table is needed to make sure the correct records are removed.

```
DELETE FROM [CData].[Smartsheet].[Sheet] S 
INNER JOIN [Database].[dbo].[Table] T ON S.[Field] = T.[Field] 
WHERE T.[Complete] = 'TRUE'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems like your SQL query is the cause of the problem.

Try this.

```
DELETE S FROM [CData].[Smartsheet].[Sheet] S 
INNER JOIN [Database].[dbo].[Table] T ON S.[Field] = T.[Field] 
WHERE T.[Complete] = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: I tried doing both Delete S and Delete S.* but both options still gave me the same Unexpected token encountered error.